# Django - How to add annotation to queryset for request.user

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-annotate

I want to add new field to queryset (by annotate()) according to `request.user`.
I have following models:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    ...
    

class Like(models.Model):
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, related_names='likes')
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='my_likes')
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=(
            ('like', _"Like"), 
            ('dislike', "Dislike")
        ),
        ...
    )
```

Now I want to execute following query:

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.all().annotate(user_reaction=some_method(request.user))
```

And I want to this annotated_field(user_reaction), reaction of user to the tweet.
`user_reaction` has 3 states:
1- Like
2- Dislike 
3- None (user hasn't like/dislike the tweet)

I want to have something like `tweets[10].user_reaction`, and after that get one of 3 states that came before. (just `like`, `dislkie` or `None`)
How can I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cast some_method with `Value()`

```
tweets = Tweet.objects.all().annotate(user_reaction=Value(some_method(request.user)))
```